# Windows Server 2012 More Than 2 RDS not allowed w/ 5 user CAL applied

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I installed Windows Server 2012 and was able to connect 2 remote desktop users as expected. When the 3rd tried to connect it said you had to kick off one of the two simultaneous users currently on.

So I purchased a Per-User 5 license Open CAL and applied it. It is listed correctly as installed in the Remote Desktop Licensing Manager. Total licenses 5, available 5, everything looks great.

However, trying to connect a 3rd user via Remote Desktop to this server still gives the same error. I have done this before in Windows Server 2008 without a problem. Any ideas? I have the Remote Desktop Service role installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the downvote for the question, but here's what worked for me:

Add the Remote Desktop Session Host role.

Apparently that has to be there for it to work properly.